# how to copy every new event in google calendar from this time to another calendar via API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to make an auto copy for every new event (ussualy an reccursive event) to another google calendar, via API.

i tried to do it with this code, but it copy also old events that their date are in the future.

```
    function copyEvents() {
  var calendarSource = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarSourceId");
  var calendarDestination = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("calendarDestinationId");
  var eventToCopy = calendarSource.getEvents(new Date("February 6, 2016 EST"), new Date("July 22, 2100 EST"));


  for (var i in eventToCopy){
    var newEvent = calendarDestination.createEventSeries(eventToCopy[i].getTitle(), eventToCopy[i].getStartTime(), eventToCopy[i].getEndTime(), eventToCopy[i].getEventSeries());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the creation time of the event by calling '*Events.created*' and use '*Events:move*' to move an event to another calendar.

Here's a HTTP Request for moving an event to another calendar: POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/calendarId/events/eventId/move

For more details, follow this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move